# Resize of custom gradient button after orientation transition on Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a problem with Auto layout for my custom button.

I've created a custom class for button to add gradient color via interface builder.

```
@IBDesignable
class GradientButton: UIButton {

    private let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    @IBInspectable
    var topGradientColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            setGradient(topGradientColor: topGradientColor, bottomGradientColor: bottomGradientColor)
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var bottomGradientColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            setGradient(topGradientColor: topGradientColor, bottomGradientColor: bottomGradientColor)
        }
    }




    private func setGradient(topGradientColor: UIColor?, bottomGradientColor: UIColor?) {
        if let topGradient = topGradientColor, let bottomGradient = bottomGradientColor {

            self.layer.masksToBounds = true
            gradientLayer.frame = bounds
            gradientLayer.colors = [topGradient.cgColor, bottomGradient.cgColor]
            gradientLayer.borderColor = layer.borderColor
            gradientLayer.borderWidth = layer.borderWidth
            gradientLayer.cornerRadius = layer.cornerRadius

            layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)

        } else {
            gradientLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }

    }
}
```

With that custom class I am able to set color for gradient on Interface Builder and see the results immediately on my storyboard.

[image]

**The problem is**: When I'm switching orientation to horizontal my button is painted only half way.

[image]

It is like the new resized parameters is not applied for some reason.
What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `GradientButton` class:

```
override var bounds: CGRect {
    didSet {
        setGradient(topGradientColor: topGradientColor, bottomGradientColor: bottomGradientColor)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this help you?

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you! 
It seems though it only works in runtime (on emulator and iPhone device). 
On my Main.storyboard, after changing orientation button is still displays half-way painted. Could you please give a hint why is that the case?